# QBD Query Item by Name (DevKit)

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

How to query an item by name? I thought this might work the same as looking up a customer by name, but it seems like not.

Comment: What programming language/DevKit?  There's a .NET one, a PHP one, a Java one, etc....

Comment: The .NET DevKit and C#, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .net you can refer to the class library documentation here:
http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV2Doc/IntuitDataServicesSDK/

If you go to ItemQuery, you will se it exposes ItemElementName of return type ItemChoiceType4 enum.
If you go to the ItemChoiceType4 details, You will see it exposes, IteratorId and StartPage.
As mentioned above, Items cannot be queried by name.
Similarly for customer query on name, you can get details that it exposes Item1ElementName which returns Item1ChoiceType enum.

For all entities similarly you can search. 
Using items will not be so elusive then. :)

Also, for each entity for QBD, you can reference the docs too and refer to Query Attributes section for details.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference

Comment: Thanks (I think). I know where the doc is. Unfortunately it's not very useful. It doesn't offer much more than method signatures and data types, and there are very few explanations and no examples. IPP has been in the works for how many years now? And we can't do a simple query on item name, which is the unique identifier from the user's perspective? How are we supposed to integrate with other systems that don't happen to have the QB record ID lying around?

Comment: You are right. We are trying to improve the docs from your's and other's developers feedback. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

QBD Items can't be retrieved by name

Ref QueryFilter Docs -
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/item#Retrieving_Items_Using_a_Query_Filter